# How does Javascript ES6 "let" works behind the scene in a for loop iteration definition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) statement is advocated for usage in `for` loops as replacement for `var` declaration of the iteration variable.

By using `let` the user can forgo the usage of immediate invocation function 
to preserve the value of iteration variable for callbacks for instance.

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  let item = document.createElement('li');
  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Item ' + i));

  item.onclick = function(ev) {
    console.log('Item ' + i + ' is clicked.');
  };
  list.appendChild(item);
}

// to achieve the same effect with 'var'
// you have to create a different context
// using a closure to preserve the value
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Item ' + i));

    (function(i){
        item.onclick = function(ev) {
            console.log('Item ' + i + ' is clicked.');
        };
    })(i);
  list.appendChild(item);
}
```

If I update the iteration variable `i` at the end of the loop, the `for` structure will pick it up and use the new value in the comperator logic of the loop and transfer that value to the next execution of the block.

```
console.log("start");
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log("in loop", i);
    setTimeout(function () {           
      console.log(i);
    }, 0);
    i = i + 2;

}
console.log("end");
```

Results:

```
start
in loop 0
in loop 3
end
undefined
2
5
```

The changes in the second iteration, do not propagate to the first iteration timeout callback.

Currently I thing the `for` loop implementation create a block execution context for each iteration, transfer the iteration variable as param, and specifically extract its value after the execution of the block ends and use it in the `for` mechanism for the next iteration. But it would be interesting to know if this is true, or not, and how it is implemented.

Comment: True. Depends on the browser

Comment: Youll find how it works here https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-for-statement however, its not that readable...

Comment: Have a look at https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-forbodyevaluation and the following paragraph. How it is implemented depends on the JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much to say. Your observation is correct. There is a separate block for each iteration. So, no matter how long your timeout is, you will always see the same result.

At the end of each iteration the value of `i` will be passed to the next iteration. Since `i` is not an object, it will not be passed by reference. Thus a modification/incrementation of i in the next iteration won't affect the value of `i` in the block of the previous iteration.

Just for fun, try using an object instead of a primitive number:

```
console.log("start");
for (let i = {i:0}; i.i < 5; i.i++) {
    console.log("in loop", i.i);
    setTimeout(function () {           
      console.log(i.i);
    }, 0);
    i.i = i.i + 2;

}
console.log("end");
```

Results:

```
start
in loop 0
in loop 3
end
undefined
6
6
```

As you can see, in that case your `i.i` variable will actually be passed by reference and thus you can modify it over different iteration blocks.

Comment: *"Since i is not an object, it will not be passed by reference."* It's a common mistake to misuse the term "pass-by-reference". *Nothing* is pass-by-reference in JavaScript. Whether something is "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value" has nothing to do with the value that is passed. JavaScript is pass-by-value and objects are *represented as* references. More: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference

Comment: I see what you mean. Any suggestions on how to rephrase it?

Comment: "Since the value of `i` is a number and therefore immutable" maybe.